# How to extract the year out of a string in R

Tags: regex, r

i have a dataframe with entries looking like:
"Wittmann 2014 100 Hills Dry Riesling (Rheinhessen)" and
"Hazlitt 1852 Vineyards 2013 Riesling (Finger Lakes)"

I need to extract the years (vintage of the wine) out of the String, but only the years from 2012 till 2015...

Would be nice if someone can help me find the right code/regex in R.

Comment: `sub(".*?\\b(201[2-5])\\b.*", "\\1", s)`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Isn't `gsub(".*(201[2-5]).*","\\1",s)` enough?

Comment: @Therkel Your provided regex will also match: `x2015` and `2015x`. Where `x` is any word character (`a-z`, `0-9` and `_`) `\b` is a word boundary.

Comment: @andlrc that makes sense. Thank you for clarifying.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this regex will work for you:

```
/(\b201[2-5]\b)/g
```

[Try it online](https://www.regex101.com/r/oH9nV8/2)